# Running Redis on Windows

Tags: windows, redis

I installed Redis via this Github repo:

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis

I have Redis running successfully on a Mac at work, but run Windows at home.
I ran the msi installer, and then am using the default configuration.

Here is the contents of my cmd file:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Redis"
redis-server.exe "C:\Program Files\Redis\redis.windows.conf"
pause
```

Redis sort of starts up and says "no error" but the server doesn't actually start, here's what the command line output looks like:

[image]

Anyone have a clue what could be wrong? If I remove the pause, the command windows just closes immediately, I needed the pause to read the output at all.

Comment: It is not running in cmd, you should have a separate process called redis-server (with cmd you just started this new process).

Answer (score 1):

In your question, if you mean seeing the usual welcome screen from a non-daemonized Redis instance, you need to set `daemonize` to `no` in your `conf` file. It seems like the default config file provided has set it to run daemonized. Just `CTRL`+`C` to kill it afterwards.

You can tell if it's really working by using the provided `redis-cli` application or `telnet` and issue your commands.

You might want to enable logging instead of the usual non-daemonized mode if you will do debugging. Command Prompt's buffer size is pretty limited plus you can use the logging feature if you will use it as a Windows service (the Github project actually supports it).

Hope that helps.